# Ninject Not working in ashx

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ashx

Ninject implementation works perfectly in WebForms. But due to some reasons it does not work in ashx.

**My Code is below.**

```
public class AllPlayers : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
    [Inject]
    public IUser _user { get; set; }
    public AllPlayers(IUser user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
    public AllPlayers()
    {

    }
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var data = await _user.GetAllPlayers();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Where do you setup the di container?

Comment: in NinjectWebCommon class.

Comment: that wasn't very helpful. remember, we cannot see your code, so we have no idea what `NinjectWebCommon` is. Let me put it another way - in what phase of application lifecycle are you doing the setup?